# SSRS Indicator Expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How to use expression in the indicator tool in SSRS to choose the start point and end point. Suppose I have person table with person_id and in my report I need to show the person_id column and indicator based on the person_id.

For example for person_id from 0 - 10 I need to show red, 10 - 20 as Green. Instead of hardcoding the value i need to use the expression. I tried the following expression as

In start expression =Fields!person_id.Value>0 and End expression =Fields!person_id.Value<10.

Again for the second set.

In start expression =Fields!person_id.Value>10 and End expression =Fields!person_id.Value<20

but all the time i am getting the same color in my report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have data like this:

[image]

And the simplest possible report based on this Dataset:

[image]

I have set the **BackgroundColor** property of the detail Textbox with the following expression:

```
=Switch(Fields!person_id.Value >= 0 and Fields!person_id.Value < 10, "Red"
    , Fields!person_id.Value >= 10 and Fields!person_id.Value < 20, "Green"
    , true, Nothing)
```

This works fine for me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Drag An indicator to the respective field where you want to show ,
Go to the properties of the Indicator
then Go to Value and States in the properties tab of Indicator.
Their you have just to give the start value and end value in the respective color .